# Need help understanding quotation marks in a SQL string to be passed to linked server.

Tags: t-sql

I need to build a SQL statement to be submitted on a linked server.  The statement makes use of @parameters and case statements which contain quotation marks.

I found this Microsoft article ['How to pass a variable'](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query), which seemed ideal, however I am not able to get everything going.  It seems that the linked server is not enabled for the final and neatest suggestion of calling Sp_executesql, so I have been trying the first two examples.

To start with, here is a cut down example of my SQL statement on its own:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN FLDA = 'ABC' THEN 'DEF' ELSE 'ABC' END AS COL1 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE FLDB = @PARM
```

1, I can get the query to work when excluding the CASE statement:

```
DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(4000), @PARM NVARCHAR(10)
SET @PARM = 'ABC'
SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYLINKEDSERVER, ''
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE FLDA = '''''+@PARM+''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

However I don't understand why I require 5 quotes before @PARM and then 7(!) after it?  When coding SQL statements in a string in previous languages just 2 quotations together acted as a single.  So why 5 and 7?

2, I can't get the SQL to work at all when attempting to add the CASE statement.  I have tried all combinations of 2,3,4 quotations but to no avail:  Do I again need a certain amount of opening quotes and then a different amount of closing quotes?

```
DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(4000), @PARM NVARCHAR(10)
SET @PARM = 'ABC'
SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYLINKEDSERVER, ''
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN FLDA = ''ABC'' THEN ''DEF'' ELSE ''ABC'' END AS COL1 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE FLDA = '''''+@PARM+''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Mark

Comment: _"I can't get the SQL to work"_ Why not? What error do you get? Anyway, the best way to work this out is to compose the string in a variable and `print` that variable until you see the right result, and only then worry about putting it into a dynamic SQL command.

Comment: What does "I can't get the SQL to work" means?  crashed???  no result???  wrong result???  No one knows.  If we don't know what's wrong, how can we help you???

Comment: The simplest debugging  is to `PRINT @TSQL` and comment out the `--EXEC @TSQL`.  See what you get.

Answer (score 0):

my first question was why do I need 5 and 7 quotes, so there was no error message there, but I get the point that I could have listed some of the errors seen when I was getting the incorrect number of quotes.

However the tip to use Print was very useful, so thank you all for that!

So it transpires that I do indeed require a pair of 
quotes where a single quote is required.  However, as I am creating a SQL string within a string, I need to double that again.  So I first need to end my string with a single quote and then add 4 quotes to create the double quote required to proceed the variable - hence 5.  And likewise, I need 4 quotes to get a pair of quotes following the variable, another pair of quotes for the quote to end the statement and then a final one to wrap around the end bracket of the OPENQUERY command....I hope that sort of reads correct!

So:

```
WHERE FLDA = '''''+@PARM+''''''')'
```

Printed as:

```
WHERE FLDA = ''ABC''')
```

And for my CASE statement, I required 4 set of quotes, to equate to 2.  So:

```
CASE WHEN FLDA = ''''ABC'''' THEN ''''DEF'''' ELSE ''''ABC'''' END AS COL1
```

Printed as:

```
CASE WHEN FLDA = ''ABC'' THEN ''DEF'' ELSE ''ABC'' END AS COL1
```